# Even though my token is correct, i am getting output message as "Missing auth token"

Tags: json, swift, api

I am creating an online compile app for ipad, using the run api of glot.io, I have taken my token from there implementing the same way they guided still I am getting JSON message as

```
{
    "message" : "Missing auth token"
}
```

I am making my application on swift, and using Alamofire for api calls.

```
let headers : [String : String] = [
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization":"f49f383b-0710-494c-ad79-76cdf3970c53"
]

var body: [String : Any] = [
    "stdin": inputs,
    "files": [
        "name": "main.py",
        "content": content
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(
    "https://run.glot.io/languages/python/latest",
    method: .post,
    parameters: body,
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers: headers
).responseJSON{(response) in
    if response.result.error == nil{
        guard let data = response.data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: data)
            print(json)
            outputcode = json["message"].stringValue

        }
        catch {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    } else {
        debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
    }
}
```

They said to implement this way.

```
curl --request POST \
 --header 'Authorization: Token 0123456-789a-bcde-f012-3456789abcde' \
 --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
 --data '{"files": [{"name": "main.py", "content": "print(42)"}]}' \
 --url 'https://run.glot.io/languages/python/latest'
```

Comment: `"Authorization":"f49f383b-0710-494c-ad79-76cdf3970c53"` should be changed to `"Authorization":"Token f49f383b-0710-494c-ad79-76cdf3970c53"` in order to match the cURL command.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana i tried your way, now this error popped up Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let headers: Dictionary = ["Accept":"application/json", "Content-type": "application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer f49f383b-0710-494c-ad79-76cdf3970c53"]

var params: [String : Any] = [
    "files": [
        "name": "main.py",
        "content": content
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(
    "https://run.glot.io/languages/python/latest",
    method: .post,
    parameters: params,
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers: headers
).responseJSON{(response) in
    if response.result.error == nil{
        guard let data = response.data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: data)
            print(json)
            outputcode = json["message"].stringValue

        }
        catch {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    } else {
        debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
    }
}
```